# Oracle SQL: Not a group by expression when using coalesce()

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I'm trying to figure out why my script is giving out the error:

> ORA-00979: not a GROUP BY expression

It says the error is at line 6, column 152. If I remove coalesce() and put a random number in, then it runs the script (albeit very slow). Otherwise, it's giving me that error. I am relatively new to SQL so I'm still trying to work on optimizing scripts but for now I just want to know why it's giving me the error and if you have any suggestions.

What I am trying to do is divide a number by 1 if the divisor initially returns 0.

Thank you!

```
SELECT col1,col2,
        CONCAT(col1,col2) as "FName AND LName",
        SUM(CASE WHEN datetime between '10-04-2022 07:00:00' and '10-04-2022 10:00:00' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS "volume1",
        SUM(CASE WHEN datetime between '10-05-2022 07:00:00' and '10-05-2022 10:00:00' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS "volume2",
        SUM(CASE WHEN datetime between '10-06-2022 07:00:00' and '10-06-2022 10:00:00' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS "volume3",
        ROUND((SUM(CASE WHEN datetime between '10-04-2022 07:00:00' and '10-04-2022 10:00:00' AND errorcode=0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END))*100/COALESCE(CASE WHEN datetime between '10-04-2022 07:00:00' and '10-04-2022 10:00:00' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END,1),2) AS "percent1",
        ROUND((SUM(CASE WHEN datetime between '10-05-2022 07:00:00' and '10-05-2022 10:00:00' AND errorcode=0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END))*100/COALESCE(CASE WHEN datetime between '10-05-2022 07:00:00' and '10-05-2022 10:00:00' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END,1),2) AS "percent2",
        ROUND((SUM(CASE WHEN datetime between '10-06-2022 07:00:00' and '10-06-2022 10:00:00' AND errorcode=0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END))*100/COALESCE(CASE WHEN datetime between '10-06-2022 07:00:00' and '10-06-2022 10:00:00' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END,1),2) AS "percent3"
FROM table1
GROUP BY col1, col2, CONCAT(col1,col2)
ORDER BY col1, col2;
```

Comment: The case in your coalesce is missing the SUM. Writing a subquery that returns total counts and error counts would make this easier to read. Also your date strings are fragile, processing depends on locale. Use `to_date` to avoid ambiguity.

Comment: You may simplify the computation by using `avg` aggregate function and keeping in mind that aggregates do not account `null`. Use `avg(case when <date filter> then case when errorcode = 0 then 1 else 0 end end)`

Comment: Usually there is no reason to divide by 1 in case of sum=0,especially in your case when you have it already in another column. In such cases it's shorter and better to use `sum(a) /nullif(sum(b), 0)` - ie. return null in case of divisor = 0.